# SystemVerilog - Are multiple fork join statements mutually concurrent/parallel

Tags: system-verilog

Lets say I have task which is called an unknown amount of times by an external condition that I (the task designer) do not know, this task then must create a thread and execute a different task is parallel (for example, to receive data for a read request that was dispatched). There could be multiple calls to  `Dispatch_Tx` so multiple threads would need to be created (`Receive_Data` cannot block `Dispatch_Tx` from finishing). **(traffic may be out-of-order, and many interleaved requests must be processed simultaneously)** s. The `fork...join` syntax shows that threads created inside of it are indeed concurrent, however, are multiple `fork...join`'s themselves mutually concurrent?

```
interface ...
.
.
.
task automatic Dispatch_TX(input clk);
   .
   .
   .
  fork 
     Receive_Data();
  join_none
endtask
.
.
.
endinterface
```

So in the above example, would there be multiple threads for the Receive_Data() task.

This is written in the LRM:

Table 9-1—fork-join control options: " join_none: The **parent process continues to execute concurrently** with all the processes spawned by the fork. The spawned processes do not start executing until the parent thread executes a blocking statement or terminates."

I may be wrongfully equating process == thread, but this seems to suggest a `fork_join` is only concurrent with the parent thread.

Comment: If `Receive_Data()` is non-blocking, that is it cannot consume time, then putting a `fork` around it makes no sense. If the calls to Dispatch_TX are  from different forked threads, are you concerned about atomic execution within those threads?

Comment: Receive_Data() is blocking, so I can't get away with using a function(). The calls are made by one single for loop, however the condition for the call to be made relies entirely on the space in a queue -- which is dynamic/unpredictable.  My concern is that ```fork...join``` may be a "Queued process" i.e. the execution of each  is dependent on sequential/temporal ordering. I want to confirm that multiple ```fork...join_none``` calls each create a seperate threads to execute Recieve_Data(). From the quick read I did of chapter 9 of the LRM, I wasn't able to confirm this

Comment: I think this is relevant to my question: Table 9-1—fork-join control options: " join_none: "The parent process continues to execute concurrently with all the processes spawned by the
fork. The spawned processes do not start executing until the parent thread executes a blocking
statement or terminates." -- Seems to suggest that the concurrency is only among the fork_jone_none and the parent thread, but what about other fork_join_nones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All threads are concurrent by defintion. Does not matter how they created. https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/process-vs-thread

Comment: bit odd that fork join_none doesn't start right away after join_none is reached.

Comment: This was done to preserve some predictability in the behavior of the code the follows the join_none. Comes more into play when the fork/join_none is in a loop.